# Restoring Ingres Database from one system to another system

Tags: ingres

We want to restore the database that we have got from the client as backup in our development environment, we are unable to restore the database successfully, can any one help us to know the steps involved in this restore process? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Vijay, if you plan to make a new database out of checkpoints (+journals) made on another (physical) server, then I must disappoint you - it is going to be a painful process. Follow these instructions http://docs.actian.com/ingres/10.0/migration-guide/1375-upgrading-using-upgradedb . The process is basically the same as upgradedb . However, if architecture of the development server is different (say backup has been made on a 32bit system, and development machine is, say POWER6-based) then it is impossible to make your development copy of the database using this method.
On top of all this, this method of restoring backups is not officially supported by Actian.

My recommendation is to use the 'unloaddb' tool on the production server, export the database in some directory, SCP that directory to your development server, and then use the generated 'copy.in' file to create the development database. NOTE: this is the way supported by Actian, and you may find more details on this page: http://docs.actian.com/ingres/10.0/migration-guide/1610-how-you-perform-an-upgrade-using-unloadreload . This is the preferred way of migrating databases across various platforms.

Comment: On a side note (after 6 years when this answer was written)... My advice to you is to migrate to some open RDBMS like MariaDB or PostgreSQL. Actian totally ruined the Ingres as an "opensource" project and community as well.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how the database has been backed up and provided to you.

In Ingres there is a snapshot (called a checkpoint) that can be restored into a congruent environment, but that can be quite involved.

There is also output from copydb and unloaddb commands which can be reloaded into another database.  Things to look out for here are a change in machine architecture or paths that may have been embedded into the scripts.

Do you know how the database was backed up?